# Ограничение полей, получаемых от MongoDB, в соответствии с GraphQL запросом

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Используемые модули:

```
apollo-server-express@3.6.2
express@4.17.2
mongoose@6.2.0
```

Модель коллекции Category предусматривает несколько полей:
`name`, `decription`, `itemsInCategory`

Клиент через GraphQL запрашивает данные:

```
query {
    item {
        category {
            description
        }
    }
}
```

Нет никакого смысла делать выборку всех полей из базы данных на такой запрос, поэтому ограничиваю выборку следующим образом:

**/graphQL/resolvers/category.js**

```
module.exports = {
    category: async (parent, args, { models, fieldsFilter }, gqlModel ) => {
        return await models.Categories.findById( parent.category, fieldsFilter(gqlModel) );
    },
};
```

**index.js**

```
const fieldsFilter = function( gqlModel ) {
    let res = [];
    gqlModel.fieldNodes.forEach( fNode => {
        res = res.concat( fNode.selectionSet.selections.map( el=>el.name.value ) );
    } );
    return res;
};
const server = new ApolloServer( {
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ()=> {
        return { models, fieldsFilter }
    }
} );
```

Всё работает как и хочется - от базы данных запрашиваются только те поля, которые нужно будет вернуть клиенту, ничего лишнего.
Вот только не покидает чувство, что это велосипед (функция `fieldsFilter`).

Есть ли готовые решения?